# What's the point of expressing plurality of nouns by modifying the word?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number

First, I am certainly aware that language is dynamic and English, like all languages, has been constructed over time by usage and culture and hasn't been "engineered".  English is what it is because language is dynamic and it evolves over time because of common use and cultural shifts.

How we express plurality has always been a funny observation for me.  As an example, let's look at the word "meter".  If something is a meter in length, we say "It is a **meter** long."  No modifier is added.  However, if we are talking about something larger or smaller than the unit, "meter" is pluralized and becomes "meters".

So far, this is basic English. Now, let's observe a couple of sentences without the plural suffix added to "meter".

> He stands 1.8 meter tall.
>
> There are 1,000 meter in a kilometer.
>
> The box is .5 meter wide.
>
> I walked a few meter.

This doesn't feel natural to the English speaker but the meaning of every sentence is easily understood.  Plurality can be assumed by all contexts.  So, my question is what's the purpose of modifying the original word if plurality can easily be discerned from contextual usage?

I am aware that English has derived from other ancient languages and, likely, this mechanism has carried over from earlier forms of language. Possibly, context might not have been so clear and modifying roots may have been necessary for clearer communication.  If there is no need for plurality in our modern form of English, what was the context and nature of an ancestral language that established this mechanism?

I've studied a couple of languages, other than English, in my life.  They've all had forms of plurality/singularity that is distinguishable by modifying the root word.  However, none of those languages need the modification of the root word either.  Plurality or singularity can be understood without it.

Why do we modify nouns to express plurality when it's simply not a necessary change to understand what's being communicated?

Comment: Of course there are cases where the singular unit is used colloquially for a plural: "he's 6 foot 3" for example

Comment: What if I told an air traffic controller that there were [garble grable] plane**s** headed for an emergency landing at your airport? Would the plural marker be useful in that communicative context? Would it at least communicate to the ATC to expect more than one?

Comment: There is this phenomenon:  If your native language does not show plural in this way, then you tend to think it is unnecessary in other languages as well.

Comment: @GEdgar.  That is interesting.  I am a native English speaker but I noticed the seeming unencessity of it many years ago.

Comment: @ChrisH, is that considered grammatically correct, though? I've heard it stated that way, but "he's 6 feet 3" sounds more correct to me.  I could be over thinking that, though, since you pointed it out.

Comment: It's acceptable in speech, including between well-educated people.  I wouldn't expect to see it in formal writing. Whether it counts as grammatically correct doesn't concern me that much

Comment: @user9825893y50932 The redundancy may be of benefit but that's not the point of grammar construction. "There is a plane coming in" or "There are plane coming in" all say the same thing without the need of the word being modified for plurality sake.  The traffic controller would have to ask for the pilot to repeat the message, regardless.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 but over a bad radio channel the sibilant is at least as likely to be masked by background noise as a number.  *--s* would be a really bad choice of plural marker if the concern was ambiguity on a noisy channel

Comment: @RLH But language developed to communicate. Not to look good. Do you think the point of language is good-looking "grammar construction(s)"? Seems like a weird perspective to me. I can communicate effectively to you using terrible grammat and spelling, for that matter. I guess it depends on what one thinks the purpose of language is, and what it should function for: to develop rational forms that I agree with or to enable communication, to serve as a mean to perform functions.

Comment: In your "There are plane coming in", you mark the fact that the subject's plural by choosing a plural verb. So you're exploiting a redundancy of English when it comes to subjects, namely subject-verb agreement as to number.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 That's not my point.  My point is that grammar is formed through evolution and change with language often happens because the change provides some form of benefit.  All I'm asking is, past or present, what dictated that adding (primarily) a plural-modified to the end of words was a good cultural, language movement.  This is an "English" question, but it's also a bit of a linguistics question.  As I mentioned in my OP, this is a common occurrence.  Why is that? There must be a reason why plural modification of nouns is so common when by sentence-context, it's not needed.

Comment: @RHL Assuming that language evolves toward practical benefit seems a preconceived view of said evolution.

Comment: "So, my question is what's the purpose of modifying the original word if plurality can easily be discerned from contextual usage?" Why do you assume that contextual usage would be *as easy* to use as what we currently have? When I read the "wrong" version, I mentally stumble and it takes me about a second to get past it. (That may just be conditioning, or it may be something more fundamental.) Just because something isn't *necessary* doesn't mean that it's not *useful*. Why do we have so many synonyms or choices of word order? Would we be "better off" without them?

Comment: @RLH The point is… uh… clarity.

First, please, what’s your own mother tongue and with how many other languages’ numbering systems are you vaguely familiar?

Can you name any language that doesn’t differentiate singular and plural?

I suggest English makes less difference than most having generally only “one” or “more than one” and the rather strange “eldest…”

Many another language stretches to “one” or “more than one and up to a smallish number, such as five” and half a dozen other rules dealing with number.

Comment: There _can_ be significant differences. 'I hate dog' vs 'I hate dogs'.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you answered your own question in your opening paragraph.

> First, I am certainly aware that language is dynamic and English, like all languages, has been constructed over time by usage and culture and hasn't been "engineered". English is what it is because language is dynamic and it evolves over time because of common use and cultural shifts.

I don't mean to be dismissive. I just genuinely don't understand what other sort of answer you might be looking for.